# Get display value from referenced cell instead of Julian date?

Tags: excel, date, formula, julian-date

I am trying to find out how to stop a formula from changing the date value to Julian date when referencing a date field.

This is what is happening:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

Is it possible in excel to get the display value of a cell instead of the text value of a cell?

Comment: =IF(A1="yes",TEXT(B1,"m/d/yyyy")&" "&C1)  derived from https://superuser.com/questions/678934/how-can-i-get-the-displayed-value-of-a-cell-in-ms-excel-for-text-that-was-conv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Text()` formula to convert data into a string using a specific format you define in the second parameter:

```
=IF(A1="yes", Text(B1, "mm/dd/yyyy") & " " & C1)
```

The reason you have to do this is because the implicit concatenation of `B1` and `C1` has an output of format `String`. So Excel takes the date, converts it to a string and concatenates with `C1`. Instead of letting Excel do the string casting, we do it ourselves using `Text()` and specifying how we want the date to be formatted BEFORE the concatenation begins.

It's always a good idea to avoid letting excel figure out your formats. It's really bad at guessing.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was having a hard time finding documentation on this online. Got to wait 8 more min before I can accept.